# PHP Mysqli extension: Using IN keyword in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm doing some queries into MySQL database using MySQLi extension in PHP. I need to do a query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable WHERE id IN (2, 4, 6);
```

This is a concrete example of the query, but the number of ids inside the parenthesis after the `IN` keyword will vary. Since I want to use the `mysqli->prepare()` function (prepared statement) I would do it like this:

```
$statement->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?)");
$statement->bind_pararm("s".... something)
```

I'm not sure what to put in the bind param function, since i cant know how many IDs will actually be queried for. I couldn't find any examples how to use `IN` keyword inside prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare your statement once you need it, you could create the placeholders like

```
join(",", array_fill(0, count($ids) , "?"))
```

or something.